# count amount of transactions per type per ID in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, pivot

Having three tables

Users u

```
 ID    email

 1     ..
 2     ..
 3     ..
 4     ..
```

Transactions t

```
 userID    transactionID    productID

 1         1111             999
 1         1112             897
 2         1222             989
 3         1333             989
 4         1444             897
 4         1114             897
```

Products p

```
 productID      type

 999            Sports
 989            Fashion
 789            Fashion
 897            Sports
```

Want to create a table in which I can find the total count of type per UserID. So ultimately I want to create the following

```
UserID    Sports   Fashion
1         1        1
2         0        1
3         0        1
4         2        0
```

Tried using the following code

```
SELECT u.email, 
       p.productID, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'Sports' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'Fashion' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
from transactions t 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.ID = t.userID 
LEFT JOIN products p ON t.productID = p.productID 
group by u.email
```

Hence it does not work as hoped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join and do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    u.id,
    sum(p.type = 'Sports') sports,
    sum(p.type = 'Fashion') fashion
from users u
inner join transactions t on t.userid = u.id
inner join products p on p.id = t.productid
group by u.id
```

The problem with your original query is the use of `count()`: this aggregates function takes in account all non-null values: so both `1` and `0` are counted in. So you can either use a `sum()` (as shown above), or change the `case` expression to return `null` when there is no match, like so:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'Sports' THEN 1 END), 
COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'Fashion' THEN 1 END)
```

Side note: presumably, you want `inner join` instead of `left join`. It does not look like your data has orphan records - and `inner join` is more efficient than `left join`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c32164857c9b14664571f6d0b7f16a31)**:

```
id | sports | fashion
-: | -----: | ------:
 1 |      2 |       0
 2 |      0 |       1
 3 |      0 |       1
 4 |      2 |       0
```

Comment: @GMB . . . You should explain that you changed the `from` clause as well.